# Unable to edit a question

Tags: support, editing

I have tried to edit [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600976/ubunut-14-10-desktop-issue-launcher-and-theme-issue) question, typed summaries and clicked "submit".

I get an error that I can't edit that question.

Why do I can't? Why I can't suggest edit to it? It's even asked from user with 1 reputation point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit probably conflicted with bolzano's edit which seems to have taken place while you were editing, or was submitted for approval before it.